# How to test a django. view for correct calculated values

Tags: django

I have a simple view to recalculate values (g -> kg) in a django form to add data inside of the view and to simply re-calculate it.

Now, i want to test such view to give it the value and compare "output" How should I test it. Here is a code of view itself:

```
def weight_converter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Adder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                value_in_g = int(form.cleaned_data['added_data'])
                result_kg = value_in_g/1000
                return render(request, 'weight_converter.html',
                              {'result': result_kg, 'initial_value': value_in_g,})
            except ValueError as e:
                e.message = 'Enter the number, not the string'
                return render(request, 'weight_converter.html', {'message': e.message})
    else:
        form = Adder()
    return render(request, 'weight_converter.html', {'form': form})
```

https://pastebin.com/tUkzsUvR

Would something like this work?

```
def test_weightconverter_view_calculation(self):
    response = self.client.get('/weight_converter/', {'value_in_g': '1234'})
    self.assertEqual(response.context['result'], 1.234)
```

Thanks in advance for any advice! )

Answer (score 1):

You make a GET request, not a POST request, and the `result` is only specified with the POST request, and likely with `added_data` as key:

```
def test_weightconverter_view_calculation(self):
    response = self.client.post('/weight_converter/', {'added_data': '1234'})
    self.assertEqual(response.context['result'], 1.234)
```

Here however it would likely make more sense to do the calculations with a GET request, since there are no side effects when converting grams to kilograms.